# How to Access TurnState Data Added by Middleware in Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: botframework, middleware

I am working with the Bot Framework and Composer. I've written some middleware to log the conversation and I need to pass this history back so that it's accessible in Composer.

I have successfully used turnContext.TurnState.Add("history", jsonString); and the value is part of the state.

However I have not figured out how to access this from Composer. Composer can access "turn" but TurnState.Add adds the information at the same level as turn and it's not accessible from within Composer. At least, not that I've been able to figure out.

I can potentially do the action within the middleware but I'd prefer that the action occur within Composer proper so that it's more accessible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Or is this just the wrong way to do this?